# how to get underlying dom node in react

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I am writing an high order component. The render() function only renders the children:

```
function myHOC(BaseComponent) {
    return class HOC extends Component {
        ...
        componentDidUpdate() {
            // get somehow the children's node
        }
        ...
        render() {
            return children;
        }
    }
}
```

I need the rendered dom node.

1. I don't know which component I will get as BaseComponent
2. I can't assume anything about BaseComponent implementation.

Therefore I don't know how I can use refs under those conditions.
Now that findDOMNode is deprecated - what else can I do in order to get the underlying dom node?

Comment: Can you make any assumptions on the children? Why do you need the underlying dom node?

Comment: If `children` is arbitrary element, you can't. The rendering of React component can result in multiple DOM nodes, or no nodes at all. Consider explaining your case, this could be XY problem.

Comment: I am trying to write HOC that debug why a component re-rendered. In order to show the result, I want to create an overlay over the component. For that I need to attach that overlay to some dom node and position it correctly.
@LorenzHenk I can't assume a thing since this is a common use.

Comment: So what you actually want to do is hook into the `BaseComponent`s `componentDidUpdate`, right?

Comment: Right, and add a div with info on top of it.